# Would it be possible to accelerate the evolution process of select animals?

Tags: evolution

I am talking about the advanced species in the Great Apes family. By accelerating the evolutionary process, I mean to gift apes with greater intelligence. We would be using science, possibly some nanobots to boost the Apes' brain.

Comment: Can you tell us about the technology of your world? Is it possible to accelerate evolution with stone age tech No. Is it possible to accelerate evolution in a world with the accelerate evolution spell Yes. Without knowing the specifics of your world this question isn't really answerable.

Comment: We generally wait up to 24h before accepting an answer. This gives the opportunity for other people to react. These people might also have more desirable answers.

Comment: Of course selection can be used to develop specific characteristics.  Just look at the variety of dogs descended from the ancestral wolf, fancy chicken breeds, or Darwin's pigeons.  The problem is in defining intelligence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is somewhat of a common misconception regarding evolution here. There is no such thing as "more evolved", there is only well adapted for a given environment. Accelerating evolution does not nessicarily mean an increase in intelligence, if intelligence is not beneficial in the current environment. When you say "By accelerating the evolutionary process, I mean to gift apes with greater intelligence", those are two different things.

However, I assume that you want a method to use natural selection to increase intelligence. If for some reason you were required to use natural selection to make intelligent apes, you probably could but it would be inefficient, and you would have to control the environment very carefully. You could breed millions of apes, find the most intelligent (by whatever metric you choose) 100,000 apes, kill the rest, let the 100,000 breed back to a high population, and repeat. Do this for several thousand millennia and you might get "intelligent" apes given that you choose your metric for intelligence properly.

Answer (score 3):

**Selective breeding**

Without using future technologies we can already do a *lot*. Our breeding programs are a great example. Look at things like pumpkins and corn. The wild versions in most cases don't have their edible parts as big as the cultivated ones. Or look at animals. Horses, cows and dogs. We have created a large variety of impressive specimens. There's dogs unrecognisable from their original wolf state, like Chihuahuas, or dogs that are adapted to water with webbed paws, hollow hairs for retaining heat and instinct to assist people in the water. Theres a very, very large variety thanks to forced breeding.

Not all attributes can as easily be selected for. There's many breeds with breathing problems, or walking, or have permanent headaches as their skulls are too small. This is partially because they were focusing on some other attributes and got forms of inbreeding. This is also partially because the desired traits can lead to the deficiency, like the breathing problem with many flat nosed dogs.

Regardless it shows that with enough patience and a *lot* of selective breeding you can get very far.

I imagine intelligence is easy to select for up to a point. Increases in intelligence will become harder, as the structure of the brain needs to evolve over time, as well as the skull. See the difference in size and shape of human and ape heads. As humans did transform without outside help (if we don't believe some crazy theories), it is entirely possible a huge breeding program can produce increasingly intelligent apes in a relatively short time. With a large enough population many inbreeding problems can also ve solved.

**CRISPR-CAS**

CRISPR-CAS is a DNA technology still in development. It used to be that DNA techniques could, at best, choose two out of the following. Cheap. Specific. Usable for multiple people. Can be mass produced. CRISPR-CAS suggests it can do all of the above. Long story short, bacteria their immune system has some enzymes. These can be high jacked to search for a certain DNA sequence and replace it with a desired code. Right now we're at a stage that we know what it does, but do not yet understand everything. We're just snipping away code we want to change and replace it with code we know works. Eventually you hope that the technique does what it promises as well as being able to basically build the desired DNA you want from the ground up.

Even before that this technique can assist you. It can help with preventing defects or inbreeding problems. That can also increase the pool of eligible breeders. With experiments you can also try to force some evolution and gaining more knowledge on what is a stable method to get higher intelligence. If you know enough, you can basically get a fertilised egg, decide what you want it to be, change the whole DNA and build you the best thing you need.

There are some restrictions though. You can't build more chromosomes. You can maybe reduce a chomosome to basically nothing by removing as much of the sequences as possible, but I have no idea how much longer or shorter a DNA string can be with this method. Still, this technique gives a lot of options to improve intelligence together with breeding.

**On electronic improvements like nanobots**

Nanobots and many other improvements are debatable. If small enough, nanobots can maybe change DNA. Improving intelligence thanks to nanobots or cybernetics is debatable. If you put a computer inside a guy that makes him act smarter, is it the person who is more intelligent? But more damning, if the guy gets offsping, does it transfer to them? Of not, it's not really evolution.

Electronics can only assist in evolution of intelligence if it's persistent throughout the generations. Though we will discuss about it now, later we'll definitely accept electronics as part of our intelligence.

Nanobots to improve intelligence is something I'm sceptical about, but the future is undetermined. I can be wrong. I do think we will have some cybernetics implanted that can assist our brain. We can already implant electronics to aid hearing. We might be able to decode some more of the brain and place a computer somewhere to help us with advanced arithmetic, some specific memories or implement it in our visual cortex to retrieve certain visual stimuli.